# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher

Tags: java, android, apk

Tengo un proyecto en el cual lee si es la primera vez que se inicia la aplicación, lo hago por medio de *sharedpreference*:

Main:

```
//Primer inicio
        boolean muestra = getValuePreferencePrimerInicio(getApplicationContext());
        if (muestra) {
            saveValuePreferencePrimerInicio(getApplicationContext(), false);
            setPreferenceInt(getApplicationContext(),6,"puntos");
        }
```

Método `getValuePreferencePrimerInicio`:

```
public boolean getValuePreferencePrimerInicio(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean("primerInicio", true);
    }
```

Método `saveValuePreferencePrimerInicio`:

```
public void saveValuePreferencePrimerInicio(Context context, Boolean mostrar) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("primerInicio", mostrar);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Lo hago para poder agregar "puntos" al usuario por el primer inicio, pero es como si no se ejecutara y no lo hace, o como si se quedaran datos de haberla tenido instalada antes, la desinstalo y la vuelve a instalar por medio del *debug*. Funcionaba perfectamente como está, pero en algún momento dejó de hacerlo y en el run me aparece esto:

```
07/16 09:34:01: Launching 'app' on HUAWEI MAR-LX3A.
Connected to process 11939 on device 'huawei-mar_lx3a-A4N4C19813000332'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.example.parlerfrench#10323#256
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/0403-0201 state=mounted key=com.example.parlerfrench#10323#256
I/le.parlerfrenc: QarthPatchMonintor::Init
    QarthPatchMonintor::StartWatch
    QarthPatchMonintor::WatchPackage: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/com.example.parlerfrench
I/le.parlerfrenc: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/all
    QarthPatchMonintor::Run
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.example.parlerfrench#10323#0
    apicache path=/storage/0403-0201 state=mounted key=com.example.parlerfrench#10323#0
I/le.parlerfrenc: QarthPatchMonintor::Reading
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent before read
I/AwareBitmapCacher: init processName:com.example.parlerfrench pid=11939 uid=10323
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@814a5db
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@db58878
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11939 SIG: 9
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.parlerfrench/com.example.parlerfrench.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 12010 on device 'huawei-mar_lx3a-A4N4C19813000332'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/le.parlerfrenc: QarthPatchMonintor::Init
    QarthPatchMonintor::StartWatch
    QarthPatchMonintor::WatchPackage: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/com.example.parlerfrench
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/all
    QarthPatchMonintor::Run
I/le.parlerfrenc: QarthPatchMonintor::Reading
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent before read
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.example.parlerfrench#10323#256
    apicache path=/storage/0403-0201 state=mounted key=com.example.parlerfrench#10323#256
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.example.parlerfrench#10323#0
    apicache path=/storage/0403-0201 state=mounted key=com.example.parlerfrench#10323#0
I/AwareBitmapCacher: init processName:com.example.parlerfrench pid=12010 uid=10323
W/AwareLog: AwareAppScheduleManager: system version has changed
D/AwareAppScheduleManager: webViewOpt, system or app version update, clearData
D/HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory: HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory in.
I/HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory: add HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory to memory.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite not found.
W/le.parlerfrenc: Unsupported class loader
V/ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21800
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21800
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:15
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 15
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
V/HwWidgetFactory: : successes to get AllImpl object and return....
I/DynamiteLoaderV2: [71] AdsFdrDynamite.integ
W/le.parlerfrenc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.parlerfrenc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/DynamiteLoaderV2: [71] Measurementdynamite
W/le.parlerfrenc: ClassLoaderContext type mismatch. expected=PCL, found=DLC (PCL[] | DLC[];PCL[/data/app/com.example.parlerfrench-EYMYgchiFQA_Dl4QJgOtwg==/base.apk*1978371040:/data/app/com.example.parlerfrench-EYMYgchiFQA_Dl4QJgOtwg==/base.apk!classes2.dex*3844201848])
    Found duplicate classes, falling back to extracting from APK : /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000cd/MeasurementDynamite.apk
    NOTE: This wastes RAM and hurts startup performance.
    Found duplicated class when checking oat files: 'Landroid/support/v4/media/MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionResultReceiver;' in /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000cd/MeasurementDynamite.apk and /data/app/com.example.parlerfrench-EYMYgchiFQA_Dl4QJgOtwg==/base.apk
I/OverScrollerOptimization: start init SmartSlideOverScroller and get the overscroller config
    get the overscroller config
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite not found.
D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{e1aefd9 token=android.os.BinderProxy@db58878 {com.example.parlerfrench/com.example.parlerfrench.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@db58878
D/ConnectivityManager: requestNetwork and the calling app is: com.example.parlerfrench
I/FA-Ads: App measurement initialized, version: 29013
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=com.example.parlerfrench, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=false
I/FA-Ads: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
I/iGraphics: [0020080c] pn: com.example.parlerfrench, p: 12010
    [0030080c] no spt app: com.example.parlerfrench
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/le.parlerfrenc: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;->mAccessibilityDelegate:Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
E/: APS:IFLoad:importExternalFunctions, search function createNewHwApsUtils failed, dlsym err:undefined symbol: createNewHwApsUtils
D/: APS:importExternalFunctions OK
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=707ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=9376348017918, Vsync=9376348017918, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=9376349180339, AnimationStart=9376349288151, PerformTraversalsStart=9376349291797, DrawStart=9376853891797, SyncQueued=9376878685026, SyncStart=9376879026172, IssueDrawCommandsStart=9376880606901, SwapBuffers=9377049970964, FrameCompleted=9377056244401, DequeueBufferDuration=146000, QueueBufferDuration=1573000, 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode jank list is null
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=745ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=9376364645563, Vsync=9377081312201, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=9377094456380, AnimationStart=9377094582943, PerformTraversalsStart=9377095088151, DrawStart=9377100813151, SyncQueued=9377104319401, SyncStart=9377104572005, IssueDrawCommandsStart=9377104755860, SwapBuffers=9377108994401, FrameCompleted=9377110543880, DequeueBufferDuration=89000, QueueBufferDuration=792000, 
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x767efbfa90 disconnect failed
D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=12010
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@38fb84f
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1832)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1880)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:741)
        at cg.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414083@20.24.14 (120408-0):1)
        at cg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414083@20.24.14 (120408-0):6)
        at lu.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414083@20.24.14 (120408-0):10)
        at lf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414083@20.24.14 (120408-0):3)
        at dz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414083@20.24.14 (120408-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at ja.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414083@20.24.14 (120408-0):6)
```

Ojalá alguien pueda apoyarme, gracias.

Anexo toda mi clase main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private static MainActivity activity_main;
    private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";
    private fragment_fav fragment_fav;
    private fragment_estadisticas fragment_estadisticas;
    private fragment_home fragment_home;
    private ArrayList<Texto> arrayTextos;
    private String URL_TEXTOS = "";
    private NetworkConnection networkConnection;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String ip = getString(R.string.ip);
        URL_TEXTOS=ip + "????";
        activity_main = this;

        //Modo oscuro
        String modo = getPreferenceString(getApplicationContext(), "dm");
        if (modo.equals("No existe") || modo.equals("sistema")) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
        } else {
            if (modo.equals("oscuro")) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            }
        }

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        fragment_fav = new fragment_fav();
        fragment_estadisticas = new fragment_estadisticas();
        fragment_home = new fragment_home();

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 0);

        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment_estadisticas, getResources().getString(R.string.titulo_stats));
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment_home, getResources().getString(R.string.titulo_home));
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment_fav, getResources().getString(R.string.titulo_fav));
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_bar_chart);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_voice);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_favorite_border);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        //Tab de home seleccionada
        tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(1));


        //Inicia Check internet
        networkConnection=new NetworkConnection(getApplicationContext());
        networkConnection.observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean) {
                //Si no hay conexión
                if(!aBoolean){
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Noconnection.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });



        //Primer inicio
        boolean muestra = getValuePreferencePrimerInicio(getApplicationContext());
        if (muestra) {
//Quiero agregar sólo 6 puntos en el primer inicio
            saveValuePreferencePrimerInicio(getApplicationContext(), false);
            setPreferenceInt(getApplicationContext(),6,"puntos");
        }
    }


    public void setBadge(int tabIndex, int num) {
        BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = tabLayout.getTabAt(tabIndex).getOrCreateBadge();
        //Pone un número si lleva uno diferente a 0
        if (num != 0)
            badgeDrawable.setNumber(num);
        badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> fragmentsTitle = new ArrayList<>();


        public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
            super(fm, behavior);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragments.add(fragment);
            fragmentsTitle.add(title);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentsTitle.get(position);
        }

    }

    public String getPreferenceString(Context context, String nombre) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String dato = preferences.getString(nombre, "No existe");
        return dato;
    }

    public void setPreferenceString(Context context, String dato, String nombre) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(nombre, dato);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getValuePreferencePrimerInicio(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean("primerInicio", true);
    }

    public void saveValuePreferencePrimerInicio(Context context, Boolean mostrar) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("primerInicio", mostrar);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public int getPreferenceInt(Context context, String nombre) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getInt(nombre, 0);
    }

    public void setPreferenceInt(Context context, Integer numero, String nombre) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt(nombre, numero);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void guardarPreferenceUltimaFechaRecompensa(String fechaRecompensa) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("fechaRecompensa", fechaRecompensa);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String leerPreferenceUltimaFechaRecompensa() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ultimaFecha = preferences.getString("fechaRecompensa", "No existe");
        return ultimaFecha;
    }
    public void guardarPreferenceUltimaFechaWha(String fechaRecompensa) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("fechaWha", fechaRecompensa);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String leerPreferenceUltimaFechaWha() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ultimaFecha = preferences.getString("fechaWha", "No existe");
        return ultimaFecha;
    }
    public void guardarPreferenceUltimaFechaFB(String fechaRecompensa) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("fechaFB", fechaRecompensa);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String leerPreferenceUltimaFechaFB() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ultimaFecha = preferences.getString("fechaFB", "No existe");
        return ultimaFecha;
    }
    public void guardarPreferenceUltimaFechaTwi(String fechaRecompensa) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("fechaTwi", fechaRecompensa);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String leerPreferenceUltimaFechaTwi() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ultimaFecha = preferences.getString("fechaTwi", "No existe");
        return ultimaFecha;
    }

    public ArrayList cargarTextos() {
        fragment_home.playLoading();
        arrayTextos=new ArrayList<>();
        URL_TEXTOS="?????";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_TEXTOS, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response;
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("textos");
                            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Texto texto=new Texto(object.getInt("id"),object.getString("texto"),
                                        object.getString("autor"),object.getString("origen"), object.getString("nivel"));
                                arrayTextos.add(texto);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            fragment_home.getRefresh().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            fragment_home.stopLoading();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("error", "error trycatch: "+response.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        //Se refresca el fragment home
                        fragment_home.onResume();
                    }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                fragment_home.getRefresh().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                fragment_home.stopLoading();
                                if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                    Log.e("ErrorConexion", "Connection Error: " + error.toString());
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.nointernet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else{
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Log.e("errorResponse", error.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                5000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        VolleySingleton.getInstanceVolley(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        fragment_home.onResume();
        return arrayTextos;

    }

    public static MainActivity getmInstanceActivity() {
        return activity_main;
    }

    public  ArrayList<Texto> getArrayTextos(){
        return arrayTextos;
    }

    public TabLayout getTabLayout() {
        return tabLayout;
    }

    public void comparaCadenas(String original, String speech){
        String[] palabrasOriginal, palabrasSpeech;
        //Se separan las palabras por cada espacio
        palabrasOriginal=original.split("[ ]");
        palabrasSpeech=speech.split("[ ]");
        //Se quitan los puntos, comas y puntosycomas en cada palabra
        String palabra;
        for (int i=0;i<palabrasOriginal.length;i++){
            palabra=palabrasOriginal[i].replaceAll("[\\.|\\;\\,]","");
            palabrasOriginal[i]=palabra;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<palabrasSpeech.length;i++){
            palabra=palabrasSpeech[i].replaceAll("[\\.|\\;\\,]","");
            palabrasSpeech[i]=palabra;
        }
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.ajustes:
                Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity_Ajustes.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void registrarFav(int id) {
        AdminBD admin = new AdminBD(this, "textosFav", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDatos= admin.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor existeTexto = BaseDatos.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM textosFav WHERE id=" + id, null);
        if (!existeTexto.moveToFirst()) {
            ContentValues insertar=new ContentValues();
            insertar.put("id",id);

            BaseDatos.insert("textosFav",null, insertar);
        }
        BaseDatos.close();
        fragment_fav.recargar();
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> devuelveFavs() {
        ArrayList<Integer> salida = new ArrayList<>();
        AdminBD admin = new AdminBD(getApplicationContext(), "textosFav", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDatos = admin.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor textosFavs = BaseDatos.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM textosFav", null);

        textosFavs.moveToFirst();
        while (!textosFavs.isAfterLast()) {
            salida.add(textosFavs.getInt(textosFavs.getColumnIndex("id")));
            textosFavs.moveToNext();
        }
        BaseDatos.close();
        return salida;
    }
    public boolean isFav(int id){
        AdminBD admin = new AdminBD(getApplicationContext(), "textosFav", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDatos = admin.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor textosFavs = BaseDatos.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM textosFav WHERE id="+id, null);
        if (textosFavs.getCount()>0) {
            BaseDatos.close();
            return true;
        }else{
            BaseDatos.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void quitarFav(int id){
        AdminBD admin = new AdminBD(this, "textosFav", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDatos= admin.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor existeTexto = BaseDatos.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM textosFav WHERE id=" +id, null);
        if (existeTexto.moveToFirst()) {
            BaseDatos.delete("textosFav","id="+id,null);
        }
        BaseDatos.close();
        fragment_fav.recargar();
    }
}
```

Cabe mencionar que funcionó cuando eliminé todos los datos de la aplicación y la volví a abrir.

Comment: Agrega el metodo setPreferenceInt()

Comment: Ya existe amigo

Comment: Preguntaba si lo podrías agregar

Comment: Anexé toda mi clase main porque también hago uso de una JsonObjectRequest, no sé si tenga que ver. Sólo quité el link de mi request por obvias razones. Gracias.